# How to detect type of Form Field in Template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Hi guys i have simple Django Form , but I need to  get  type of  this field elements and  I made  some special operations  according to this.

Is there an  easy  way to  get type of  Form Field in Django Template?

Any  help  will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "type of this fields elements"? The widget that is used to render the field? Or the model field class ... ? Could you elaborate a bit on your "special operations"?

Comment: For example, I have ImageField  but in my form I want to make visible  existing ImageField with  upload field like twitter user profile... So I need to  get type of field and I do required  operation according to this.

Comment: In your "form" oder in your "template"? To me it sounds like you are trying to create a custom widget for a form field (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/). Are you thinking of something like this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2419/ ?

Comment: let me  have a look at this  cheers

Comment: I'm not mentioning exactly  about  admin forms, But  you  gave  me what I want. How can I use it in my simple form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your actual use case the [image widget](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-form-utils/0.2.0#imagewidget) from the [django-form-utils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-form-utils/) package should be a good match.

On more general level: If you simply want to modify the html generated by a standard widget you should subclass the widget and tweak the render-method.

Take a look at this [blog post](http://johnmee.com/2010/07/django-widget-renderer-render/) to get the basic idea.